# Attempting to run a while loop in my select statement under cases in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server

## The Data

Let us say I have a field in SQL that consists of multi-line Information, each of which consists of i topics, each topic consisting of m points of information.  Topics are prefaced with 'i.' and information with a dash. It looks something like:

```
________________________________________________
|Number | Information                           
|===============================================
|1      | 1. Topic 1.1                           
|       |     -Info 1.1.1                       
|       |     - ... [more info]
|       | 2. Topic 1.2
|       |     -Info 1.2.1
|       |     - ...[more info]
|       | ... [more topics]
|_______|_____________________________
|2      | 1. Topic 2.1
|....and so on
```

## The Current System

What I am doing with this information is to parse out each topic into it's own column, then unpivoting those columns and searching for Topics that contain a given keyword @keyword.

Currently the code reads something like:

```
Select 
    Number
    ,Case When Information LIKE '%1. %2. %'
          Then substring (Information, charindex('1.',Information),
                    charindex('2.', Information) -(charindex('1.',Information)+2) )
     Else Information
     End as [Topic1]
    ,Case When Information LIKE '%2. %3. %'
           Then substring (Information, charindex('2.',Information),
                    charindex('3.', Information) -(charindex('2.',Information)+2) )
     Else 'N/A'
     End as [Topic2]
     ...repeat 2nd case for each set of numbers up to  '%20. %21. %'
```

The only reason the first one is different is because if it doesn't match the pattern then I want to grab the whole field so that I don't miss anything. I then `unpivot` the Topic fields that I just created into a general `[Topic]` field, and then utilize a `WHERE [Topic] LIKE '%' +@keyword+'%'` to pull out any particular topics and their associated case number to output as my final table. The cases can have anywhere from 1 to 40+ topics attached, with 1-7 attached info fields per topic.

## The Desired Modification

**Notice:** To make the code easier to read, I will not be writing my substring code in proper syntax, instead opting to write `substring(Information,ci(@Iter), ci(@Iter+1)-ci(@Iter))` to denote the substring running from the position given by '(iter).' to the position given by '(iter+1).'

What I would like to do is to perform the following:

```
  Declare @Iter smallint
  Declare @Result varchar(max)

  Select
      Number
      , Set @Iter=1
        Set @Result = ' '
        Case When Information LIKE '%'+@keyword+'%' --keyword chosen at front end
             Then While @Iter < @n --@n set by the user from front end
                  Begin
                  Case When Information LIKE '%' + cast(@Iter as varchar(5))
                        + '. %'+cast((@Iter+1) as varchar(5))+'. %' 
                        and substring(Information,ci(@Iter), ci(@Iter+1)-ci(@Iter) )
                        LIKE '%'+@keyword+'%' 
                        Then  Set @Result = @Result +substring(Information,ci(@Iter), 
                                ci(@Iter+1)-ci(@Iter) )
                  Else Set @Result = @Result end
             Set @Iter = @Iter +1
             End
       Else ' ' end [Result]
```

## The Explanation

In case what I want isn't clear, I'll run through what I'm trying to accomplish

> I want to output a list of case numbers that include Topics that include the keyword.
>   For each case in the list I want to output ***only*** those topics that include the keyword.
>   I want to allow the end user of the report to choose how many Topics in each case they'll search.
>   I don't want to have to create a table with a column for each Topic when I can't know how many the user will want to create.

Due to these considerations it feels like a loop would be the best option, but there are problems in trying to accomplish that.

## The Problem

> 1. SQL server won't allow me to utilize a loop in my Select statement--`Incorrect syntax near 'While'`.
> 2. The place where the information comes from prohibits normalization of the information in the table I'm searching
> 3. Even if it didn't I am barred from creating my own permanent tables at work, so I can't normalize the data for all incoming data
> 4. I am also not allowed to write my own stored procedures.

If there is any way (for example through a cte) to implement these changes, I'm open to hearing them! I'm mostly looking at ways to make the code less daunting looking (20 cases to produce 20 fields in my current cte looks scary, which then needs 3 ctes just to unpack properly [unpivot, removal of certain cases meeting certain conditions, combination into a workable output table])

Thanks in advance for reading this and helping!

Comment: That is because a loop is used to control the flow of logic, not build up some sort of dynamic query. If you really need to do this you will need to use dynamic sql in a loop to build up your query. Then execute the string you built. The challenge as I see it is the limitations of your company. You can't be successful with this unless you can normalize your data and/or write your own procedure. If you need detailed help you need to provide us with some details. Check out this article. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: I suppose using CLR is out of the question?   Are you allowed to write a UDF?

Comment: @Tab I had to ask another Analyst; as far as we could tell, the general analyst login to the database does not have the required permissions. I sent a quick message to the DBAs and hope to get a personal login that does soon.

Comment: Of course nobody wants any kind of sensitive data posted. That is certainly not the point. The point is to post some data (hopefully nonsense data) that represents the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're working too hard.
If all you need are topic names and numbers, isn't it easier to split the Information column by newlines, and then collect all lines that start with a number and not a "dash" by then, you will have a list of strings that look like:

1. Topic 1.1
2. Topic 2.1

And then it's easy to just match the lines against the keyword?

Something like this untested SQL:

```sql
select SUBSTRING(s.value,1, PATINDEX('% %', s.Value) - 1) AS topicId
, SUBSTRING(s.Value, PATINDEX('% %', s.Value), LENGTH(s.Value)) AS topicText
from [table that would make Codd cry] t
cross apply STRING_SPLIT(t.Information, CHAR(13)) s
where s.Value LIKE '[0-9]%' -- Starts with a number
AND s.Value LIKE @keywords --matches keywords
```

Not sure if you can create functions or you have STRING_SPLIT available in your SQL Server version, but if you don't, there are some string splitting CTEs you can find on the net to do the job for you